# Qual è il significato di "girare intorno all'osso" e "azzannare l'osso" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Sostiene Pereira*, di Antonio Tabucchi, ho letto:

> Mi sta telefonando il direttore, disse al ritratto di sua moglie, mi pare che **giri intorno all'osso** ma non l'**ha ancora azzannato**, non capisco cosa vuole da me, ma deve **azzannare l'osso**, tu che ne dici?

La mia domanda è sulle espressioni "girare intorno all'osso" e "azzannare l'osso" che appaiono in questo brano. Si tratta di modi di dire? Potreste spiegarmene il significato? Ho cercato alla voce "osso" in alcuni dizionari, incluso il dizionario di modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Comment: Si riferisce al tipico comportamento dei cani che prima di saltare su una preda, in questo caso l'osso, ci girano intorno per farsi un'idea più precisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo caso l’espressione viene usata in modo figurato: il direttore ha un obiettivo che il narratore non riesce ad identificare bene, e sta girando intorno all'osso, cioè sta per arrivare al suo scopo.

Il narratore dice che si aspetta un atto da parte del direttore per raggiungere l’obiettivo.

Immagina una scena simile agli squali che girano intorno alla preda inerme in mare: prima o poi uno attaccherà e azzannerà l’osso.

Oppure, come correttamente segnalato da @egreg:

> Si riferisce al tipico comportamento dei cani che prima di saltare su
>   una preda, in questo caso l'osso, ci girano intorno per farsi un'idea
>   più precisa.

Comment: A me più che gli squali (che hanno questo comportamento solo nei film...) fa pensare ai cani.

Comment: Squali, cani o lupi, tutti girano intorno alla preda. Comunque concordo con te

Comment: Il concetto di osso come preda è tipico dei cani, almeno come li si rappresenta usualmente.